# Override third-party/helper/library functions in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

I don't know its easy or hard but I am not getting. How to override the core functions of the third-party libraries I have searched lot but not get even single idea about this.

Scenario: I have added the FPDF library to 'application/third-party' folder and I have included it in the Controller. And I need to create multiple pdf files using same library, in different controllers. So in each pdf files I want change header and footer styles, for that I need to override the 'header/footer' functions of the FPDF library class.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: try creating another model/lib whatever that extends the main fpdf class and include the header/footer functions there. then load that model/lib and work off that.

Comment: @alex Any example links or if possible paste here only.